# Error parsing text-format caffe.NetParameter: 9:24: Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "image_pair_data_param"

Tags: python, windows, deep-learning, caffe

I am trying to train the caffe model with windows system. 
However, when I use "caffe.exe train --solver=d:/tools/config/fcn_solver.prototxt", there is something wrong.

```
errors:
[libprotobuf ERROR ..\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:274] Error parsing 
text-format caffe.NetParameter: 9:24: Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" 
has no field named "image_pair_data_param".
F1225 21:16:49.415436  5732 upgrade_proto.cpp:79] Check failed: 
ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: 
D:/tools/config/fcn.prototxt
```

I know the message may shows that my fcn.prototxt is wrong at the line 9.

```
   name: "fcn"


   layer {
   name: "pairdata"
   type: "ImagePairData"
   top: "data"
   top: "label"
   image_pair_data_param{
   image_dir: "/AerialImageDataset/train/images"
   label_dir: "/AerialImageDataset/train/gt"
   batch_size: 10
   h_img: 256
   w_img: 256
   h_map: 256
   w_map: 256
   channels: 3
   mean: 0
   scale: 1
   multiclass: false
   }

   include: {phase: TRAIN}
   }
```

---

```
I have no idea what's wrong with my image_pair_data_param. I have tried using the absolute path, but it is no work.
I am using the vs2013 ,anaconda3 and win10.
By the way, the training model is from https://github.com/emaggiori/CaffeRemoteSensing/tree/master/InriaBenchmark
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of caffe are you using? where did you got this model from?

The default caffe version has no `image_pair_data_param` defined in the [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto) file, you should look at the caffe branch that was used to train this model and see what modifications were made to `caffe.proto` in that branch.

Comment: I think my caffe is version 1.0. I download it from the github and then compile it with vs 2013. And I got the model from the github https://github.com/emaggiori/CaffeRemoteSensing/tree/master/InriaBenchmark. I know the image_pair_data_param is the new layer that the author add. I have checked that in caffe.proto, it has defined it so this layer should be okay to include.

Comment: no. you need to compile the same version of caffe as the author of the model used. you need to compile with **his** caffe.proto.

Comment: @9576alice please.see.my comment